# Angular with Redux on windows

Tags: angular, redux

I receive the following error when calling `ng serve`:

Class `NgRedux<RootState>` incorrectly implements interface `ObservableStore<RootState>`.
Property `[Symbol.observable]` is missing in type `NgRedux<RootState>` but required in type `ObservableStore<RootState>`.

My `package.json` looks as follows:

```
{
    "name": "angular-with-redux",
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "scripts": {
        "ng": "ng",
        "start": "ng serve",
        "build": "ng build",
        "test": "ng test",
        "lint": "ng lint",
        "e2e": "ng e2e"
    },
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "@angular-redux/store": "^10.0.0",
        "@angular/animations": "~8.2.4",
        "@angular/common": "~8.2.4",
        "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.4",
        "@angular/core": "~8.2.4",
        "@angular/forms": "~8.2.4",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.4",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.4",
        "@angular/router": "~8.2.4",
        "redux": "^4.0.1",
        "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.8",
        "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
        "rxjs": "^6.4.0",
        "tslib": "^1.10.0",
        "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.803.3",
        "@angular/cli": "~8.3.3",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.2.4",
        "@angular/language-service": "~8.2.4",
        "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
        "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
        "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
        "@types/redux-logger": "^3.0.7",
        "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
        "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
        "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
        "karma": "~4.1.0",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
        "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
        "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
        "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
        "protractor": "~5.4.0",
        "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
        "tslint": "~5.15.0",
        "typescript": "~3.5.3"
    }
}
```

I know that this question is already asked, but non of the proposed solutions helped me.

Currently I can't run Angular with Redux. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] or at least he related code.

Comment: why don't you use  https://ngrx.io/ instead ?

Answer (score 2):

If you pin `redux` to the specific version, then you don't hit this error. There seems to be a dependency problem in versions after 4.0.1.

In `package.json` (note, removal of `^`):

```
// ...
  "dependencies": {
    // ...
    "redux": "4.0.1",
```

Answer (score 1):

Refer the below link

https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/issues/3466

The cause for the above issue is collision of redux version.Restricting the strict version of redux solves the above issue